# file.createFile does not work. Android 10

Tags: android, kotlin, local-storage

```
 val filePath = getString(R.string.file_path)
    val file = File(filePath)
    var lines: List<String?> = ArrayList()
    if(!file.exists()) {
            try {
               if (Environment.getExternalStorageState()==Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) {

                   file.createNewFile()
               }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(getString(R.string.No_records_file))
                    .setMessage(getString(R.string.cant_create_file))
                    .setNeutralButton(
                        R.string.Exit
                    ) { dialog, id -> finish() }.show()
            }
        }
```

It works on Android 8.0.0, 9.0   . I am not sure about android, but this problem appeared on Mi9T pro

Comment: `file.createNewFile()` still is usable under Android 10. But not for every path. And you did not tell your path.

Comment: It create file in "/storage/emulated/0/Documents" folder, if it does not exist, it create this folder. As I understand system allows access only to "Downloads" folder

Comment: It works on android version below 10, as I wrote. For 10 and over I have to use something else. I see it is not many exemples, what  can help to understand

Comment: It's strange that you dont ask which paths you still can use.

Comment: Ok, i'll lookup tomorrow. so wich one path or paths is available?

Comment: I'm must be blind, but i cant find what paths is available for directly access.

Answer (score 2):

With Android Q, you can no longer directly access to the file system. Use the SAF (Storage Access Framework) instead.

Comment: Can I just grant permission with provider and work with file like I did it before?

Comment: No you can't. And, as the SAF asks the user where he wants to store the file, you don't need the `WRITE_ACCESS` permission any more. The SAF acts as the Java `JFileChooser` class you may already know.

Comment: SAF make user to use UI? All exemples are about this needless feature in my app. But many apps from market are create folders and files without this ui dialog. Is it using DocumentProvider?

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to implement a class derived from it if you only want to use either the internal storage or an SD Card.

Comment: if I wont to create database, I also need do it throw SAF?

Comment: No you don't. Just use the SQLite database as with earlier versions of Android.

Answer (score 1):

First add this rules;

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Ask permissions from activity;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    //ASK HERE...
    if (shouldAskPermissions()) {
        askPermissions();
    }

}
```

-

```
  //// ASK METHODS
    protected boolean shouldAskPermissions() {
        return (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1);
    }

    protected void askPermissions() {
        String[] permissions = {
                "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
                "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        };
        int requestCode = 200;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
        }
    }
```

then for create file use this code;

```
        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+java.io.File.separator +"AppName");

             try{
                     if(!directory.exists()) {
                         System.out.println("Directory created");
                         directory.mkdirs();
                     } else {
                         System.out.println("Directory is not created");
                     }

                     File f = new File(directory.getPath()+"/"+ "ENTER_FILE_NAME" + ".jpg");
                     f.createNewFile();
                     FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                     fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                     fo.close();

                     System.out.println("FILE PATH:" + f.getPath());

                 }catch(Exception e){
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

on Android API 29, getExternalStorageDirectory is deprecated, you should use getExternalFilesDir instead.